# Como sumar filas con condición de columnas con Pandas o Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, tablas

He estado trabajando con un archivo csv el cual ya he limpiado un poco, lo que me interesa saber es como sumar los valores de mi columna "Global_Sales" pero separándolas por los años de otra columna, por ejemplo, sumar todas las de el 2006, luego las de el 2007 y así hasta el 2016, pero que los valores de sumas totales se queden en la misma tabla.

| Publisher | Year | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nintendo | 2006 | 5 |
| Nintendo | 2006 | 8 |
| Nintendo | 2007 | 3 |
| Nintendo | 2007 | 4 |

Son mas de 10000 valores, pero pongo eso como ejemplo, en realidad "Publisher" no importa porque todos son Nintendo, pero si me gustaría sumar todos los de cada año y que quedara en una tabla similar a esta.

| Year | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 2006 | 13 |
| 2007 | 7 |

Y así sucesivamente con cada año.
Muchas gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: `df.groupby("Year").Sales.sum()`

Comment: Eres un dios jaja me dormí a las 4 de la mañana buscando y no encontré nada, y con ese código lo resolviste todo en verdad gracias

Comment: Ahora en la columna no me sale el encabezado de "Sales", Sabes cómo se lo puedo agregar?

Comment: Eso es porque el resultado no es un dataframe, sino una "Series", que no tienen nombres de columna. Otra forma de hacerlo que creo que sí te produciría un dataframe sería seleccionar una lista de columnas para sumar, pero que en este caso tendría una sola: `df.groupby("Year")[["Sales"]].sum()`, o bien `df.groupby("Year").sum()[["Sales"]]`

Comment: Lo que hice fue pasarla a lista de nuevo con un "tolist()",  pero solo me quedaron los valores de la suma, y ya agregué de nuevo la lista con los años, hice un diccionario y lo hice DataFrame de nuevo y me sirvió para Gráficar que era lo que quería, creo di mucha vuelta, pero funcionó. GRACIAS